# Local Server for Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I just installed Windows 8 Release Preview and my existing wampserver does not work. I tried installing easyphp and after the service was successfully started it can't find the localhost.

Is there any fix to this or other local servers to run php and phpmyAdmin the easy way ?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I already tried uncommenting the 127.0.0.1 address while using wamp.